# JavaScript AND / OR Operand

Tags: javascript

The priority of AND && is higher than OR ||. That's why it works before OR.

In the example below, `1 && 0` is calculated first.

```
alert( 5 || 1 && 0 ); // 5
```

I don't understand how this happens?

Comment: The `||` operator takes the left hand side as long as it is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).  So `5 || /*anything*/` is 5.

Comment: no it isn't. it's evaluating left to right like it's supposed to. `5` is a truthy value so it stops then and there since you're using the `||` operator

Comment: What do you not understand, exactly? Do you understand why 5 + 2 · 3 = 11 and not 21?

Comment: This is just a convention and it is how the language is implemented. Here's the complete list of [operators precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: See [Does JavaScript have "Short-circuit" evaluation?](/q/12554578/4642212).

Comment: As you said, `&&` has an higher precedence over `||`, and then the condition can be rewritten `(5) || (1 && 0)`, the same way multiplication has an higher predecence over addition, `5 + 1 * 0` is equivalent to `(5) + (1 * 0)`

Comment: Are you trying to do bitwise operations like [`| OR`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_OR)?

Comment: Your question would make more sense if it were `5 || foo() && bar()` and you wonder if foo and/or are bar are ever called.

Answer (score 0):

The left-hand side will be evaluated first. Please see example

```
a || (b * c);  // evaluate `a` first, then produce `a` if `a` is "truthy"
a && (b < c);  // evaluate `a` first, then produce `a` if `a` is "falsy"
a ?? (b || c); // evaluate `a` first, then produce `a` if `a` is not `null` and not `undefined`
a?.b.c;        // evaluate `a` first, then produce `undefined` if `a` is `null` or `undefined`
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 0):

Please check **[Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)** for more details.

Order is from left to right, when any of the early left part evaluates to be true, the rest of right side is not evaluated and is omitted.

```js
console.log(5 || false); // 5
console.log(true || 5 || false); // true
console.log(false || 5 || 10); // 5
console.log(false || 10 || 5); // 10
```